# How can I know my `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` correspond to the alias of `steady_clock` or `system_clock`, or other?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

How can I know my `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` correspond to the alias of `steady_clock` or `system_clock`, or other?

Many websites and books are providing examples using the `system_clock`, that might be goes back due to the synchronization, to measure the time spent for a function.
I don't think that is the good idea to measure the time.
Instead, I think we should use `std::chrono::steady_clock`.

Sometimes `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is used.
According to the URL https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock , it says *"It may be an alias of `std::chrono::system_clock` or `std::chrono::steady_clock`, or a third, independent clock."*

So, I want  to know how can I check which aliases my `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` correspond to.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::is_same`?

Comment: Personally I ignore `high_resolution_clock` and use `system_clock` (wall time) or `steady_clock` (timing stuff) as appropriate. I think it is unlikely the resolutions of those clocks will be much, if any, lower than whatever `high_resolution_clock` points to.

Comment: _"I think we should use `std::chrono::steady_clock`."_ -- so do that. Why are you concerned about `high_resolution_clock` when you want to use `steady_clock`?

Comment: You can look at the header. That's probably the most reliable way to know what `high_resolution_clock` is for your platform. @Galik is correct: use the right clock for the right job. `high_resolution_clock` is likely never the correct clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from  Sam Varshavchik's comment. You can use `std::is_same` from `<type_traits>` to check if two types are the same.

Here's an example for checking the three standard clocks in `chrono`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_same_v<system_clock, high_resolution_clock> << '\n'
        << std::is_same_v<system_clock, steady_clock> << '\n'
        << std::is_same_v<high_resolution_clock, steady_clock> << '\n'
    ;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MHBCdv)

Comment: If `is_same` is `false`, you cannot be sure the clocks are actually different. They may internally use the same low level clock source.

Comment: @AndreySemashev True - but that'd be a really bad alias. If the type check does not result in `true` _something_ should be different.